# Output Line Number of Search Word

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a program to output the line number of a search word from a text file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
    while (index >= 0) {
        index = fileText.indexOf(searchWord, index + 1);
        indexOfSearch.add(index);
    }
    System.out.println(fileText);//print the text from file
    for (int j = 0; j < indexOfSearch.size() - 1; j++) {//each index of search word
        String spaces = "";//spaces to caret
        int indexTo = 0;//how many spaces will be added
        if(j < 1){
        indexTo = indexOfSearch.get(j);//the first index
        }else{            
            indexTo = (indexOfSearch.get(j) - indexOfSearch.get(j - 1) - 1);//all other indexes in the row
        }            
        for (int i = 0; i < indexTo; i++) {//add appropriate number of spaces to word  
            spaces += " ";//add a space
        }
        System.out.print(spaces + "^");//print the spaces and spaces
    }
    System.out.println("");//used to make the print slightly easier to look at.
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this helps you on your way. I built you a class you can call for each line you read in.

This can easily be plugged into your current code. If you need help integrating it in, I am more than happy to help.

I broke it down almost step by step in the comments.

```
public class FindWord {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        FindWord f = new FindWord();

        f.findWords("As you can test, we can put as many test in test as we test", "test");
    }


    public void findWords(String str, String search) {//This can easily be added into your project

        String fileText = str;//text from file
        String searchWord = search;//the word being searched
        List<Integer> indexOfSearch = new ArrayList<>();
        int index = fileText.indexOf(searchWord);
        indexOfSearch.add(index);
        while (index >= 0) {
            index = fileText.indexOf(searchWord, index + 1);
            indexOfSearch.add(index);
        }
        System.out.println(fileText);//print the text from file
        for (int j = 0; j < indexOfSearch.size() - 1; j++) {//each index of search word
            String spaces = "";//spaces to caret
            int indexTo = 0;//how many spaces will be added
            if(j < 1){
            indexTo = indexOfSearch.get(j);//the first index
            }else{            
                indexTo = (indexOfSearch.get(j) - indexOfSearch.get(j - 1) - 1);//all other indexes in the row
            }            
            for (int i = 0; i < indexTo; i++) {//add appropriate number of spaces to word  
                spaces += " ";//add a space
            }
            System.out.print(spaces + "^");//print the spaces and spaces
        }
        System.out.println("");//used to make the print slightly easier to look at.
    }

}
```

I created a string with multiple words that are being searched for to show how it works.

If there is a requirement I missed, please let me know and I will fix it accordingly.

I hope this helps!

EDIT: I put everything together and included updated requirements The entire source can be found here:

[SO_AustinProject](https://github.com/SynchroDynamic/SO_AustinProject)

Comment: Your class was helpful in allowing me to edit my program, but I have edited the question. After implementing your code, I am only able to have the carets align if there is one line of text in the file. I would like the carets to align for more than one line of text.

Comment: You would want to pass your "line" variable and "searchWord" variable into the method. If you would like me to edit my answer to have your class and my class work together I can.

Comment: The more I have the easier. I can put it into github when complete. I would have to do it later tonight though. Would that be ok?

Comment: I've updated my code again. I have it all working now except for the issue I present in the edit. Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: I am working your code presently. I will add that before I post it.

Comment: I created an account.

Comment: I updated my answer with the github repository where the code is located. If you want me to remove the code once you have it, just let me know.

Comment: Thank you - I am indebted to you. Is the reason why you have a file output path is because you are creating a new text file for the output? If so, I will remove that because I would like the output in the CMD interface.

Comment: I just added a few extra things, just to give you options. You also have a file choice option by popup. I am not sure if you saw that. I am glad you like it.

Comment: It appears I'm having an issue with the program outputting the "Line number" as described in my edit. I did modify the classes you provided a bit to satisfy my needs. Hope you can help..

Comment: So you would like each line to be something like  "1 > the dog...", "2 > a test..." With that you would want to add a "int count = 1;" outside of your while loop, then call it in system.out. finally you would want to add 1 to count inside the while loop. This should achieve the desired output.

Comment: Ok - I would just like it to state, "Line Number 1" or "Line Number 2" above the caret identifier line if the search word is found on the respective line.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that only in a fixed width font can you predict the location of something by counting characters. Most fonts are 'variable'. so that 'lllll' is narrower than '0000' for example. So basically if you can control the font and go with Courier for example (google 'fixed width fonts') you will be able to use spaces to locate the caret, but other than fixed font it's basically impossible to do this

Comment: My thought, as you might be able to tell from the code, was to find the index of the first letter of the search word in any line. I can do that. Now, my thought was to shift the line below with the ^ by an int holding the value of the index. This is where I was struggling.

Comment: I guess i'm totally confused. You seem to be writing multiple carets based on an value you already know is the starting place right? So what's going wrong? Wouldn't you just write the number of spaces that is the index of where the string is found and then write ONE caret? What is it doing wrong?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure how to write this and if the word is located more than once in each line, I will need more than one caret.

Comment: You aren't sure how to output spaces? Or not sure how to get the number of spaces? What are you hung up on?

Comment: I know how to output spaces. I cannot hard code this. If the text file contains more than one line, I need to have it output spaces per the discovered index on the next line regardless of the number of matches. This would require me to shift the caret over by each index found. I know how to shift, but I do not know how to shift by set variable(s).